# Customizing FluentValidation .net core web modelstate behavior

Tags: asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

Out of the box, when FV detects validation failures, it surfaces the property name, error messages, attempted value as an array, and returns it as a BadRequest response.

However, FV's validator.Validate() method actually returns a much richer ValidationResult object and includes metadata about error codes, and parameterized values.

I'd like to be able to return the actual ValidationResult, including all that rich metadata, rather than just some of the data from the validationfailures.

How can I change this behavior? (.net core 2.1 btw).

Comment: Did you ever find a way to solve this?  I am currently looking for the same functionality.  Unfortunately, some of the FV classes are internal....